# HTTP Get Requests (Wordpress website Rest API calls) not working in iOS App (Ionic4 and angular)

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

My Ionic4 App (with angular) is published in both PlayStore (Android) and App Store (iOS). The app is expected to show the latest articles from a Wordpress based website. The app makes a HTTP GET request to fetch JSON data (calling the WordPress rest API at URL https://website.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts). Sample code from page ts file:

```
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

this.http.get(url).pipe(map(res => {return res}));
```

My app is working fine in Android but failing to display content in iOS devices.

Apple Support team is unable to help as they only look into swift code. For Ionic code, they are suggesting to get help from Ionic community experts. This issue has blocked our release and became a show stopper for us. I request you to help us resolve this issue at the earliest.

Regards,
Nanda Kishore

Comment: Hi , did you solve this, I am having the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same issue in which `iOS` device fails to make HTTP calls but `android` works fine.

First I've detected the `platform` using `Platform` helper class whether the platform is `iOS` or not and then tried the same call with adding `user-agent` while making `http` call.

```
callWithUserAgent(url: string) {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; " + "Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)"
      }
    }
    return this.httpClient.get(this.baseUrl + url, config);
  }
```

This worked for me.

Adding `user-agent` sounds crazy but you can try atleast. Make sure you add `user-agent` in small caps.